# How to create a ripple effect when clicking on the touch screen using the camera

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to create a nice ripple effect when you click on the touch screen for my game. My only constraints are I need it to use the camera and not an image. I've tried downloading a couple off the asset store and they haven't worked how id liked.

Any references, videos, anything is appreicated

Comment: google is your reference mate :)

Comment: I have googled for over 30 minutes

Comment: _"I have googled for over 30 minutes"_ - [Forth from the top](https://www.google.com.au/search?q=unity+3d+ripple+effect&ie=&oe=#newwindow=1&q=unity+3d+image+ripple+effect).  For my next trick...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to create a nice ripple effect when you click on the touch screen for my game. My only constraints are I need it to use the camera and not an image

Why use the camera? You can apply camera *transforms* but generally such transforms are global and I'm not sure how to apply a "ripple" effect that way.

It's easier and more efficient if you render your image to a **render target**; apply it as a **texture** to a **mesh**; and use a **vertex displacement shader** where vertices for each point in the quads are displaced over time using a ripple function of your own chosing (say a touch of sin/cos in 2D).

[tell me more](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/594863/distortion-effect-free-unity.html)

Comment: Thank you ill check them out